# How to open .movie file in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, video, multimedia

I am trying to open a `.movie` file in Ubuntu 18.04. When I double click I get a message saying `Could not display [filename].movie`.

Can you please point me to some applications to install that will open `.movie` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
xdg-open <file_name.movie>
```

Otherwise a good alternative is to dowload and install [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html).

> VLC is the VideoLAN project's media player.
>
> Completely open source and privacy-friendly, it plays every multimedia file and streams.

Comment: I tried. I get this: `xdg-open kazam_h1xyaw00.movie 
gio: file:///home/xx/Videos/myfile.movie: No application is registered as handling this file`. I need to open the file by double click. I do not want to use the terminal every time I want to open the file.

Comment: Then try to install VLC media player, does it works ? Note that it is available from Ubuntu Software.